# Alternative method to find maximum point

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, functions, maxima-minima, moment-generating-functions

I'm trying to find the point where the maximum of my function occurs. Because the function does not yield trivial expressions of derivatives, I can't just differentiate and find the root. I'm trying to find an alternative method and I'm not aware of any. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Context: the function is positive definite, defined for x in $[0,\infty]$. It has a bell-shape, but is non-symmetrical.

Sidenote: I do have a general expression for the values of its moments, of all orders. I was hoping that using the order 1 moment (mean, in a distribution sense) I would get it, but because the function is non-symmetrical, the mean would differ from the max. 
So is there a method, that I may not be aware of, which allows finding where the maximum occurs, using the moments (or something else for that matter)?

Comment: Do you need an exact location of the maximum, or a numerical approximation of it? And when you say "positive definite", do you mean that $f(x) > 0$ for all $ x \in [0, \infty)$?

Comment: @JohnHughes I would prefer the exact location of course, but if I get a decent approximation that can be of use also. Yes I mean $f(x)>0$, except for $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Numerical answer (assuming you have good numerical precision on your computer): exponential search followed by bisection.

Details:

Part 1: Set $c = 1$; compare $f(c)$ to $f(2c)$. If the latter is smaller, you're done; if not, double $c$ and repeat.

At this point, your max lies between $a=0$ and $c$.

Part 2: You have a max somewhere between $a$ and $c$; you'd like to narrow it down. Let $A = f(a)$ and $C = f(c)$. Let $\phi \approx 1.618...$ denote the Golden Ratio, and let $b = (\phi-1)a + (2-\phi)c \approx 0.618a + 0.382b$, and let $B = f(b)$. Because $f$ "has a bell shape" (which I take to mean that the maximum is unique), and $a < b < c$, the value $B$ should be greater than either $A$ or $C$, or something's terribly wrong.

You have a triple $(a, b, c)$ of domain values.

Repeat until $a$ and $c$ are close enough to satisfy you:
   Pick $d = a + (c-b)$.

If $D = f(d)$ is greater than $B$, proceed with the triple $(a', b', c') = (b, c, d). $

Otherwise, proceed with the triple $(a', b', c') = (a,b,c). $

In each case, the distance $c' - a'$ diminishes by at least a quarter, so that eventually $c'-a'$ will be arbitrarily small.

This is called "[Golden Section Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden-section_search)".